# What does 'As is True For' Means

Tags: phrases

The following sentence has the phrase of "as is true for", what does that mean?

Each Individual corporation owner does not have individual legal responsibility for the corporation's actions, **as is true for** the owners of a sole proprietorship or partnership.

Does it mean that the sole proprietorship or partnership have individual responsibility for the company's actions?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it does. But it isn't expressed as clearly as it could be. A better way of putting it would be "as do the owners of a sole proprietorship or partnership".

Comment: I’d replace “as is true for” with “unlike.” The sentence is badly drafted, claiming what is true is the unnegated  condition of a negated statement. Fire those lawyers.

Comment: I understood now and thank you for the explanations!